# How to use rxjs filter with Angular 2's async pipe

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a `Observable` that I am trying to filter but I cannot seem to get it to display properly in my view.

```
comments = new Rx.BehaviorSubject([
    {body: 'foo', commentable_type: 'Client'},
    {body: 'foo', commentable_type: 'Client'},
    {body: 'foo', commentable_type: 'Purchase'},
    {body: 'foo', commentable_type: 'Client'},
    {body: 'foo', commentable_type: 'Payment'},
]);

comments$ = comments.asObservable();

clientCommentStream$ = this.comments$.filter(comment => comment['commentable_type'] === 'Client');
```

and in my view, this works perfectly:

```
<li *ngFor="let comment of comments$ | async">
    {{ comment.body }}, {{ comment.commentable_type }}
</li>
```

but this displays nothing:

```
<li *ngFor="let comment of clientCommentStream$ | async">
    {{ comment.body }}, {{ comment.commentable_type }}
</li>
```

My [stack blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ld5aeu) shows that the filtering is working, but it won't display because it seems the structure of the object has changed.  Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: On http://stackblitz.com it would be easy to create a full Angular reproduction.

Comment: I made it.  Still can't figure it out https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ld5aeu

Comment: The correct link is https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ld5aeu

Comment: my apologies, new to stack blitz

Comment: The stackblitz also contains entirely different code. In you question you have an observable of objects and in your stackblitz you have an observable of array of objects.

Comment: maybe that's what im misunderstanding

Comment: If you pass an array, you need to remove all items from the array that don't match your criteria. If you pass the items individually, you need to collect them to an array afterwards because `*ngFor` expects an array, not a sequence of individual items. `scan` should do that as far as I remember.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense.  Thank you

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer how would you use it in my case to filter?

Comment: I don't know what you try to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

you are missing return statement

```
clientCommentStream$ = this.comments$.filter(function(comment) {
    return comment.commentable_type == 'Client'; <-- missing "return"
})
```

OR use arrow function

```
clientCommentStream$ = this.comments$
                       .filter(comment => comment.commentable_type == 'Client')
```

**EDIT:**
used `Rx.Observable.from` instead of `Rx.BehaviorSubject`

from docs BehaviorSubject emits most recent item, not sure how it works

Comment: I edited my question because while this was incorrect it was not the casue of my error

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/g5pj065m/210/ tried using Observable.from instead of BehaviorSubject

Comment: I guess having the `iterator` makes a difference here